# How to calculate "Average Brightness" and "Average Brightness (var)"

Tags: python, image-processing

There two metrics used LLVE (low light video enhancement), which are "Average Brightness" and "Average Brightness (var)". I have no idea how to calculate these two metrics. You can refer to this [article](http://bmvc2018.org/contents/papers/0700.pdf).

I have tried to calcuate "Average Brightness (var)" by following code, but I don't know it's right or not.

```py
ABs = []
for i in range(len(imgs1)):
    AB = np.abs(imgs1[i].mean() - imgs2[i].mean())
    ABs.append(AB)
AB_var = np.var(ABs)
```